# Error while executing Pause Azure SQLDatawarehouse ps script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-synapse

I am using Automation Account with execution of PowerShell Runbook for Pausing my Azure Datawarehouse database.
Setup is completed with creation of crendentials, certificate for Thumbprints. 
When I executed the PS script and completed with error message

> No Azure SQL Data Warehouse named ADWPOC exist on SQL Server  At SuspendOrPauseAzureSQLDataWarehouse:72 char:72 + + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

I have provided the name of database and server details correctly while executing this script. I am not sure what is the problem here. Please advise.

I have imported the PS script from runbook gallery "Suspend Or Pause Azure SQL Data Warehouse". Please let me know if you want me to attach the script here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but the script looks too old, it still uses the [`AzureRm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/overview?view=azurermps-6.13.0) module which has been deprecated.

To pause the data warehouse in the runbook, I recommend you to use new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.8.0) module, [`sample here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-reference-powershell-cmdlets#pause-sql-data-warehouse-example), to use that in runbook, just follow the steps as below.

1.Navigate to your automation account in the portal -> `Modules`, make sure you have imported the `Az.Accounts` and `Az.Sql` modules, if not, in the `Modules` -> `Browse Gallery`, search for the modules and import them.

2.After importing the modules successfully, navigate to the `Runbooks` -> create a `PowerShell` runbook(not the `PowerShell Workflow`), then use the script as below in the runbook.

**Note**: The `<server-name>` should be like `testserver`, not `testserver.database.windows.net`.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$database = Get-AzSqlDatabase –ResourceGroupName "<resource-group-name>" –ServerName "<server-name>" –DatabaseName "<data-warehouse-name>"
if($database){

    if($database.Status -eq 'Paused'){
        Write-Output "The Data Warehouse was already paused."
    }else{
        $database | Suspend-AzSqlDatabase
        Write-Output "The Data Warehouse has been paused." 
    }

}else{

    Write-Output "The Data Warehouse does not exist."
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for sharing the script and steps for installing modules. It ran successfully. Thanks again