# Runbook automation fails but powershell cmd line works fine

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have the following powershell code for suspending azure d/w

```
$TenantId = "<>"
$SubscriptionId = "<>"


# Get the service principal credentials connected to the automation account. 
$SPCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "psvar"

# Login to Azure ($null is to prevent output, since Out-Null doesn't work in Azure)
Write-Output "Login to Azure using automation account 'psvar'."
$null = Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $TenantId -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -Credential $SPCredential

Write-Output "Login Status " 
# Select the correct subscription
Write-Output "Selecting subscription '$($SubscriptionId)'."
$null = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionID $SubscriptionId

$ResourceGroupName = '<>'
$ServerName = '<>'
$DatabaseName = '<>'



Write-Output "Suspending $($DatabaseName)..."
$null = Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase `
        -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName`
        -DatabaseName $DatabaseName`
        -ServerName $ServerName


Write-Output "Done"
```

Suspend azure rm sqldatabase works fine in PowerShell Azure Command line interface
But in runbook automation it fails with

```
Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
At line:33 char:9
+ $null = Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase `
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Suspend-AzureRmSqlDatabase], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.DatabaseActivation.Cmdlet.SuspendAzureSqlDatabase
```

Any idea what could be wrong. Appreciate any pointers regarding this

Answer (score 0):

I test your script, it works in the runbook.

[image]

Navigate to the automation account -> `Credentials`, make sure your user account name and password are correct.

[image]

If it still not work, you could try [my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58549085/error-while-executing-pause-azure-sqldatawarehouse-ps-script/58554505#58554505), it works.

Comment: Thank you, my account is federated AD a/c thats why it is not working.

Comment: @Shiv I use a work account in the AAD tenant which is in the subscription, you can also use the run as account, refer to the last link in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Synapse analytics we need to use

```
Update-AzSynapseSqlPool -WorkspaceName <wsname>-Name <dbname> -Pause
```